# Referencing a theorem goes to the wrong page

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a situation where using `\cref` from package `cleveref` to reference a theorem seems to create a hyperlink to the wrong page. The link points to the page where the theorem was supposed to be typeset, before latex decides to fill that page with other floats. That page directly precedes the one where the theorem finally ends up at.

I have tried some ideas from

[wrong page with pageref if using thmtools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88468/wrong-page-with-pageref-if-using-thmtools)

but none worked. It seems that the target of the link is created before the position where the theorem is typeset is fixed.

Any way one can work around this?

**EDIT**

I experimented with moving the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` commands after the theorem.

The theorem now gets typeset at the top of some page, but the link goes to the bottom of the page immediately preceding that.

I then inserted a `\clearpage` right before the theorem, and it fixes the problem.

However, this solution does not scale well, obviously. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide us with a minimal example, where the suggested answers don't work?

Comment: `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` commands would not only start a new page, but also would instruct LaTeX to print queued tables and figures. Hence, you may use this command before referencing a float. But with this approach, you may need to move contents around so that you will not wind up with a page with too much of empty space

Comment: Does changing the order in which cleverref and hyperref are loaded matter?

Comment: ! Package cleveref Error: cleveref must be loaded after hyperref!.